# Global Okhttp3 interceptor in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp, user-agent

Is there a way to set a global interceptor for Okhttp3 in a Spring Boot application?

The goal is to set a custom *User-agent* header for all the requests (without having to modify every single piece of code where we define an OkHttpClient object)

Comment: if your okhttpclient will be spring-managed bean - aspects is a good thing to choose. If not - you can define some proxy class for OkHttpClient and add your custom logic inside and use it instead of raw OkHttpClient

Comment: or as an option you can define okhttpclient factory, that will prepare clients for you (e.g. add interceptor to client on build phase)